# Kill VSCode explorer file loading

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to develop on a remote server and my runs tend to generate large, compressed files which are not human readable. Sometimes I inadvertently click on one of these files in the explorer and VSCode attempts to load/open it. Whenever this happens, it just gets stuck on loading and that VSCode window is essentially unusable. I've only ever let it sit for a handful of minutes, but it never seems to finish loading.

So in each of these cases, I have to close the window, open a new one, and reconnect. Also any unsaved changes I have to c+p to my local machine and then back. Is there a way to just kill the loading/opening sequence?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?